# "SQLite manager query Error"

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to update column of one table from another table

```
UPDATE tbl_relations SET tbl_relations.WANTED = table_wanted.WANTED FROM table_wanted , tbl_relations  WHERE table_wanted.M_V_NO = tbl_relations.M_V_NO
```

And Error message in SQLite manager is

```
near ".": syntax error:
```

Comment: Please review the syntax tree for the INSERT command: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (works for me in SQLite with fake data):

```
UPDATE tbl_relations
SET tbl_relations.WANTED = (SELECT w.WANTED 
                            FROM table_wanted w
                            WHERE w.M_V_NO = tbl_relations.M_V_NO) 
    WHERE tbl_relations.M_V_NO IN (SELECT w.M_V_NO
                                   FROM table_wanted w 
                                   WHERE w.M_V_NO = tbl_relations.M_V_NO)
```

Hope that helps.